# CDI Injection giving different instances across request

Tags: jax-rs, cdi

I am attempting to use CDI injection across a JAX-RS rest request.  Specifically, I have a ContainerReqeustFilter, the rest end point class and a ContainerResponseFilter.  In the ContainerReqeustFilter I have a simple bean injection:

```
public class BeanTest {
    private String content;
    public String getContent() { return content; }
    public void setContent(String value) { content = value; }
}
```

And in my ContainerRequestFilter:

```
@Inject BeanTest beanTest;
```

And in my ContainerResponseFilter I also have:

```
@Inject BeanTest beanTest;
```

However I am getting two different instances of the BeanTest bean rather than the same one which I expected. Why is this?  I expected the same BeanTest instance to be reused across the request.

I've also tried the following in one class:

```
@Inject BeanTest beanTest;
@Inject BeanTest beanTest2;
```

Again, beanTest and beanTest2 are different instances.

Finally, I've also tried:

```
@Inject @RequestScoped BeanTest beanTest;
```

and

```
@Inject @SessionScoped BeanTest beanTest;
```

Neither of which changed any noticeable behavior.  My ultimate goal is a reusable bean across the classes invoked during a rest service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any annotation on `BeanTest`, meaning, if you are using `bean-discovery-mode=all`, such beans are considered by default to be in `Dependent scope`. That implies that their lifecycle is tired to the bean in which they are injected, and a different bean instance is injected in every different bean it is used.

Use the correct scope (if you need application wide bean, ApplicationScope, etc)

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#_scope

Comment: Thanks for this!  Adding `@RequestScoped` to the BeanTest class fixed this for me and now behaves as I wanted.